# "R session aborted" while trying to install any packages

Tags: rstudio

R session is getting aborted whenever i try to install any kind of packages.[while trying to install "leaps" package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q1hP.png)

All the other packages are updated and the rstudio is also updated(Version 1.0.143).

Comment: Might be a long-shot, but have you tried changing the CRAN server `chooseCRANmirror`? Also, are your library paths `.libPaths()` local or on a network drive?

Answer (score -1):

I have had this issue and it is usually because the package is already downloaded try just using `library("package")`.